# viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind is not being called in iOS 13 device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I try to add footer view in my collection view layout with collection view delegate method `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` but it's not being called while reload collection view.

```
SeatArrangementViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource , QuiltViewDelegate ,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       setCollection()         
    }

    func setCollection()  {
       self.clnSeats.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
       self.clnSeats.register(UINib(nibName: "SeatFooterView",bundle:nil),forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "SeatFooterView")
       let space = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 262
       self.clnSeats.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: space/2.0, bottom: 90, right: space/2.0)

       let layout = self.clnSeats.collectionViewLayout as! QuiltView

       layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.vertical
       layout.itemBlockSize   = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
       self.clnSeats.reloadData()
    }
```

Collection View Methods

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind{
       case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter: .....

    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, blockSizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    // get random width and height values for the cells
    let width  = self.numberWidths[indexPath.row]
    let height = self.numberHeights[indexPath.row]

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetsForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 2, bottom: 2, right: 2)
}
```

I also add `@objc (collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:)` but that not work for me.

Comment: Please show more context. Thanks.

Comment: I update question @matt. It's working fine in live app but when I run this code today it's create issue.

Comment: OK so that's not real code.

Comment: I have only this code. Can you please help me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: It can’t be your real code. You have not declared that SeatArrangementViewController is a UIViewController. Copy and paste your real code into the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if you've registered a supplementary view.
2. Check if delegate and data source are set.
3. If you are using custom size for footer or header ensure that it returns a size that greater than zero otherwise delegate will stop trying to get a supplementary view

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
```